# Warning 1 The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2013, typescript, cordova-3

In Visual Studio Professional 2013 when I created a new Apache Cordova project, get this warning:

> Warning 1 The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation,
>   so it will skip compiling.

Few weeks before it is working fine but now I am getting this error.

I re-install VS and Tool for Apache Cordova, but still getting this error.

How to solve this error? Any solution?

Answer (score 9):

To fix this warning !

1. open your *(your project name)*.csproj with texteditor tools ( NotePad , Editplus , etc.. )
2. remove this line..

   ```
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
   ```
3. save
4. re open project.

hope this help !

Answer (score 1):

To fix this warning you can remove the  line in your `.csproj` file or `.jsproj`. You can just open this in your favorite text editor.

Offcourse if you plan to use Typescript in the future you can always add it back in the project file!

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one file marked with the build action "TypeScriptCompile".

This will then be passed to the TypeScript compiler for you. You only need to specify your "top level" file, as the compiler will walk the dependencies for you.

[image: Build Action in Properties Window]

Answer (score -2):

(Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>Build and Run>Set MSBuild project build output verbosity= Diagnostic

now you can see in console what fail!